# Python for turbidity sensor

Tags: raspbian, mcp3008

How do i interpret this code to python for my sensor

```
    void loop()
{

    volt = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<800; i++)
    {
        volt += ((float)analogRead(sensorPin)/1023)*5;
    }
    volt = volt/800;
    volt = round_to_dp(volt,1);
    if(volt < 2.5){
      ntu = 3000;
    }else{
      ntu = -1120.4*square(volt)+5742.3*volt-4353.8; 
    }
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print(volt);
    lcd.print(" V");

    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(ntu);
    lcd.print(" NTU");
    delay(10);
}
```

Comment: This question is okay, but could improve by adding some information about explaining where the code is from, what the author have tried and why it is not working. I reckong the qestion has nothing to do with turbidity sensors, but rather from using the MCP3008. But it is a bit unclear...

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

> Convert Arduino C++ turbidity measurement program to Rpi python

***Answer***

> See Appendix A below.

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Buggy Answer V0.1*

```
# printTurbidityMeasurement python program V0.1  tlfong01  2019may27hkt0926 
import time.sleep

while True

  totalVoltageReading = 0
  for count in range(800):
     currentVoltageReading = float(anlogRead(rpiGpioSensorPinNum / 1023) * 5)
     totalVoltageReading = totalVoltageReading + currentVoltageReading

  averageVolteageReading = totalVoltageReading / 800

  roundedUpAverageVoltageReading = round(averageVoltageReading)

  if roundedUpAverageVoltageReading < 2.5:
    nephelometricTurbidityUnit = 3000
  elif
    nephelometricTurbidityUnit = -(1120.4 * square(roundUpAverageVoltageReading) + (5742.3 * roundUpAverageVoltageReading - 4353.8) 

  lcd.clear()
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0)
  lcd.print(roundedUpAverageVoltageReading, "V")

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1) 
  lcd.print(nephelometricTurbidityUnit, "NTU")

  sleep(10)
```

Comment: from what library are you importing `anlogRead`, `rpiGpioSensorPinNum `, `lcd` and some other stuff? this answer is promising, but incomplete

Comment: Well, it was almost 2 years ago when I gave the answer, so I forgot what exactly happened. I vaguely remember that I understood the Op's Arduino code and so translated it to python. and waited for the OP to reply, before I improve the code. But as usual, I did not get any reply and so my short term memory was completely erased after  a couple of weeks. More over, I guess the OP' question has been heavily edited, so I could not find anything mentioned ore related to MCP3008, which I was very experienced, and therefore tried to help. / to continue, ...

Comment: I have posted a couple of answers in this forum about MCP3008/MCP3201/MCP3208. If you are interested in MCP3008, you might search this forum for my old answers. Cheers.

Comment: superb addition. thanks! have a nice weekend. :)